Stable weak equivalence is the same as being level weak equivalence after spectrification
Let $X$ be a simplicial sequential spectrum.
Let $FX$ denote a strict fibrant replacement functor of $X$, i.e., a natural transformation of spectra $X \to FX$ such that $X^n \to FX^n$ are weak equivalence of simplicial sets and $FX^n$ are Kan complexes for all $n$.
Then the spectrification of $X$ is defined as follows:
$$
Q(X)^n := colim_i\ \Omega_{S^1}^i FX^{n+i}
$$
Here $\Omega_{S^1}$ is the functor $\underline{Hom_*}(S^1, -)$ where $\underline{Hom_*}(-, -)$ denote the internal hom in the category of pointed simplicial sets.
Given a morphism of spectra $f: X \to Y$, in order to show that $Q(X) \to Q(Y)$ is a level weak equivalence if and only if $f$ induces isomorphisms on stable homotopy groups, I have to show the following:
Question 1:
Assume
$$
\pi_i(Q(X)^n) \to \pi_i(Q(Y)^n)
$$
are isomorphisms for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ where $Q(X)^n$ and $Q(Y)^n$ are equipped with the canonical base points, then
$$
Q(X)^n \to Q(Y)^n
$$
is a weak equivalence.
Question 2:
In the context of motivic spectra, how can we prove the similar proposition?
In the reference I read, it says that the choice of base points in $\pi_i(Q(X)^n, x_0)$ is independent since $Q(X)^n$ are H-spaces, but I don’t know why.

It should be possible to show that $QX^n\to \Omega QX^{n+1}$ is a weak equivalence, so that $\pi_i QX = \pi_i QX^0$.

For question 2, we can use stalks to reduce to the case in question 1.
Now for question 1, we have
$$
QX^n \to \Omega (QX^{n+1})
$$
is a weak equivalence, therefore it’s enough to show the following: given morphism of Kan complexes
$$
X \to Y
$$,
the induced morphism
$$
\Omega(X) \to \Omega(Y)
$$
is weak equivalence provided that $\pi_0$ and the homotopy groups with canonical base points induce isomorphisms.
To show this fact, we can use geometric realization and weak equivalence
$$
|\underline{Hom_*}(S^1, X)| \to \underline{Top_*}(S^1, |X|)
$$
for Kan complex $X$ to reduce to the topological case. Now since every connected component of loop space is homotopy equivalent by path composition morphism and the related commutative diagram, we can show that for each connected component there exists a base point which induces isomorphisms on homotopy groups. Finally, we use the fact that fundamental groupoid induces isomorphisms on homotopy groups to end the proof.
